# $\mu(A)= \sup(\mu(K))$, to show $\mu$ is countably additive

Tags: measure-theory

> Supppose $\mu$ is nonnegative and finite additive on $\Bbb{R}^k$ and that $\mu(\mathbb{R}^k)<\infty$. Suppose further that $\mu(A)= \sup(\mu(K))$, where $K$ ranges over the compact subsets of $A$. Show that $\mu$ is countably additive.

To show, $A_i$ disjoint, $\mu(\cup_i A_i)=\sum_i \mu(A_i)$

Let, $K_i\subset A_i$ are compact such that $\mu(A_i-K_i)< \frac{\epsilon}{2^i}$. For $\epsilon$ there exists a compact set $K$ such that $\mu(\cup_i A_i-K)<\epsilon$.

We also have $\sum_i^n \mu(A_i) - \sum_i^n \mu(K_i)= \mu(\cup_i^n A_i - \cup_i^n K_i)<\epsilon$, for each $n$.(finite additivity)

What should I next?

Comment: Note that $K=\bigcup_i K_i$ might not be compact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINTS:

Intermediate step: If $A_n $ decreases to empty set then $\mu (A_n) \to 0$. To prove this choose compact sets $K_n \subseteq A_n$ such that $\mu(A_n\setminus K_n) <\frac  {\epsilon} {2^{n}}$. Since $\cap_n K_n \subseteq \cap_n A_n$ is empty there exists $N$ such that $\cap_{i=1}^{N} K_i$ is empty. [This is  a basic result for compact sets].

Hence $\mu (A_N) =\mu (\cap_{i=1}^{N} A_i)\leq \mu (\cup_{i=1}^{N} (A_i \setminus K_i))\leq \epsilon$. It follows that $\mu (A_n) \to 0$ as claimed.

Rest is easy. If $A$ is the disjoint union  of $A_n$'s apply above result to $B_i=A\setminus \cup _{i=1}^{n} A_i$. I will leave the rest to you.

Comment: yeah! rest is easy. But what led you to think the solution in this way? (don't say brain plizz, like is it property of compactness?)

Comment: @Stat_prob_001 Many books state the fact a finitely additive measure  is countably additive iff it is continuous from above (in the sense $\mu (A_n) \to 0$ whenever $A_n$ decreases to empty set).